# Error while installing Sitecore 9 update 2 on the same computer that has a 9.1.0 installation

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

Sitecore 9.1 is already installed on the computer. SitecoreInstallFramework 1.2.1 and 2.0.0 are also installed. I am trying to use SIF 1.2.1 version in order to install Sitecore 9 update 2. I am executing below command:

Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -Force -RequiredVersion 1.2.1

I am getting below error:

```
Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "System.Object": The member HasMemberPath is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Object": The member HasMemberValue is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Object": The member ExtendWith is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Object": The member HasMember is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Object": The member GetMember is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Object": The member GetMembers is already present.
Error in TypeData "System.Object": The member GetMemberNames is already present.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -Force -RequiredVersion  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 7):

I am able to resolve this issue by following below steps:

1.) Uninstall SIF 1.2.1

```
Uninstall-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
```

2.) Install SIF 1.2.1 Again

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
```

3.) Running a specific version of SIF (1.2.1) to install sitecore 9 update 2. You may have to close powershell and then reopen powershell before running below script:

```
Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -Force -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
```