# Unable to install Sitecore 9.0.2 while having Sitecore 10

Tags: installation

Trying to install `Sitecore 9.0.2` on a machine that already has `Sitecore 10`. However, getting below error. Do I need to change the Sitecore module?

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : A registration exists for the Task 'AddWebFeatureSSL' (Invoke-AddWebFeatureSSLTask).
Use -Force to override.
output file is C:\Workspace\sc902_install\xconnect-createcert.220805.log

At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Private\RegistrationHandler.ps1:82 char:9
```

Comment: Both Sitecore 9.0.2 and Sitecore 10 use different SIF(Sitecore Install Framework), could you please make sure you are using the correct SIF version for 9.0.2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was due to module SitecoreFundamentals installed. Uninstalled it and it solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an issue with your `SitecoreInstallFramework` version and for this you need to use the accurate version to install `Sitecore 9.0.2`.

Here are some commands to check it.

**List all version**

```
Find-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -AllVersions
```

**Install a specific version**

```
Install-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -Repository SitecoreGallery -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
```

**Switching versions**

```
Remove-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework
Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
```

Use this article for more details.

https://www.koenheye.be/multiple-versions-of-the-sitecore-install-framework/

And this is something about the error you are facing.

[Error while installing Sitecore 9 update 2 on the same computer that has a 9.1.0 installation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16360/error-while-installing-sitecore-9-update-2-on-the-same-computer-that-has-a-9-1-0)